# Графики html5 js canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, диаграммы

нужна помощь, использую chart.js для построения диаграмм, все ничего, НО требуется очень большой объем данных в виде 500000 точек, с чем не справляется данная библиотека, если кто сталкивался, можете подсказать какую либо библиотеку, желательно на js.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [canvas.js](https://canvasjs.com/), возможно это то, что вам нужно. Пробовал около 100 тысяч точек, тормозов не замечал.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin это очень крутая библиотека, но ценник кусается, и у пользователя не будет доступа к интернету

Comment: Там есть бесплатные лицензии для персонального использования и для студентов, возможно это ваш случай, а возможно нет.

Comment: Попробуйте highcharts, он очень проблемный и неудобный в настройках, но кажется тянет хорошо большое количество данных.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev он ведь тоже платный(